# Nginx, Horde, Https, Redirect, This webpage has a redirect loop

Tags: php, nginx, https, horde

I have an NGINX server with Horde installed so I can use webmail, and am getting two different errors depending on whether I'm using http -or- httpS.
I have setup debug within nginx and am not getting any inclination as to what the source of the error is.
Mail error/access logs have no errors.
I have successfully setup Postfix, and Dovecot (both tested/connected from telnet and Open_ssl from CLI).
My IP-ports are open (as needed).

Http works fine (h--p://www.mydomain.not/index.php).
Http**S** does **NOT** work with this same URL.

Http**S** does load the **webmail** loginPage BUT...
1. The page doesn't look right. It looks nothing like what it did when I was using Apache2 which leads me to believe something is not processing PHP correctly.
2. I cannot login directly through this **webmail** login page, BUT I can login using the **Horde-TEST.php** page provided by Horde.
**Note**: webmail h--p://www.mydomain.not/webmail/**login**.php
**Horde-Test** h--p://www.mydomain.not/webmail/**test**.php

So....
A) regular loginPage (loads, but can't login)
(h--p**S**://www.mydomain.not/webmail/login.php)
B) Horde-Mail Test page (non-httpS) does load and the test(s) login is working for all imap/imapS and pop3/pop3S in the browser.
h--p://www.mydomain.not/webmail/test.php

-however, the test login page does not load at all if swtiched to httpS
h--p**S**://www.mydomain.not/webmail/test.php

H--p**S** will load if a specific URL is typed (h--pS://www.mydomain.not/webmail/login.php) -but I noticed that the page is graphically inaccurate. The structure of the page does not look like the Horde/Mail login page that I had when I was using Apache2.

When I setup a redirect for http to force https, the main website page not load "h--pS://www.mydomain.not/index.php", but the webmail login page still does load...-but as before it will not let me log in...keeps giving me "Error ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT".

Lastly, I have verified that my php5-fpm config file "/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf" user/group statement (nginx) and the listen statement (listen = /tmp/php5-fpm.sock) are in agreement with what's setup in my nginx.conf configuration "fastcgi_pass unix:/tmp/php5-fpm.sock;".

And I should mention, I also have prestashop loaded in the root website directory and there are no PHP errors with any of its functionality...-but I'm not suing any httpS on it at this time either...just http.

In summary:
I have errors when trying to use HTTPS.
1. http**S** will not load the main webpage.
2. http**S** will load the Horde_test page., AND the test tools connects successfully to imap/imaps/pop3/pop3s.
3. http will load the webmail login page, but gives "Error ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT".

The only known error that I am getting is from the CLI after reloading nginx whenever I've made a change to nginx.conf (even if I just add a comment line and change nothing else!) this is what happens:

/etc/init.d/nginx: 2: /etc/init.d/nginx: Syntax error: newline unexpected

-and sadly, once this happens...even the regualr main page without httpS now gives "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS"...only rebooting starts this http working again.

Here's my nginx.conf file.

### ...PREFACE...THIS !@#$ TOOL WONT LET ME POST REGULAR CONFIG WITH CONTROL CHAR'S!! -not my fault if it looks stupid.

user nginx
worker_processes 4
pid varrunnginx.pid

events 
        worker_connections 768
         multi_accept on

error_log varlognginxdebuglog       debug

http

```
     Basic Settings


    sendfile on
    tcp_nopush on
    tcp_nodelay on
    keepalive_timeout 65
    types_hash_max_size 2048

    include etcnginxmime.types
    default_type applicationoctet-stream

    access_log varlognginxaccess.log
    error_log varlognginxerror.log
```

server 
        listen   80  listen for ipv4 this line is default and implied
        listen   80 default ipv6only=on  listen for ipv6

```
    server_name mydomain.not *.mydomain.not

    Force http to use httpS
    NOTE I've turned this on ONLY to test...-same errors output for httpS noted in posting
    rewrite ^ h--ps$http_host$request_uri? permanent     force redirect http to https
```

HTTPS server
server 
        listen 443
        keepalive_timeout   70
        ssl_protocols       SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2
        ssl_ciphers         AES128-SHAAES256-SHARC4-SHADES-CBC3-SHARC4-MD5
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on
        ssl on
        ssl_certificate etcnginxsslserver.crt
        ssl_certificate_key etcnginxsslserver.key
        server_name mydomain.com *.mydomain.com

```
     ssl_ciphers ALL!ADH!EXPORT56RC4+RSA+HIGH+MEDIUM+LOW+SSLv3+EXP

pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    location  .php$ 
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?.php)(.*)$
            if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) 
                    return 404

            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.19000
            fastcgi_pass unixvarrunphp5-fpm.sock
            fastcgi_pass unixtmpphp5-fpm.sock
            fastcgi_index index.php
            include fastcgi_params


    root usrsharenginxwwwwcrc
    index index.php index.html index.htm
```

I'm not using the direct mail ports below as I'm using TLS through the browserHorde-webmail instead.

mail 
        See sample authentication script at
        httpwiki.nginx.orgImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript

```
    auth_http localhostauth.php
    pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER"
    imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS"

   server 
           listen     localhost110
           protocol   pop3
           proxy      on


   server 
           listen     localhost143
           protocol   imap
           proxy      on
```

PORTS OPEN
$ sudo netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN
tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0443 0.0.0.0* LISTEN 1744nginx
tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0993 0.0.0.0* LISTEN 938dovecot
tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0995 0.0.0.0* LISTEN 938dovecot
tcp 0 0 127.0.0.13306 0.0.0.0* LISTEN 985mysqld
tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0110 0.0.0.0* LISTEN 938dovecot
tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0143 0.0.0.0* LISTEN 938dovecot
tcp 0 0 0.0.0.080 0.0.0.0* LISTEN 1744nginx
tcp 0 0 0.0.0.021 0.0.0.0* LISTEN 831vsftpd
tcp 0 0 0.0.0.022 0.0.0.0* LISTEN 800sshd
tcp 0 0 0.0.0.025 0.0.0.0* LISTEN 1215master
tcp6 0 0 22 * LISTEN 800sshd

Answer (score 0):

There were several things wrong here, and the "answers" are not yet complete.

1. I removed the httpS config from nginx.conf.
2. I cut out almost all of the fastcgi stuff, and put in a basic config:

   server {
   server_name example.org;
   root /var/www/site;

   location / {
       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
   }

   location ~ .php$ {
       include fastcgi.conf;
       fastcgi_pass unix:/tmp/php-fpm.sock;
   }
   }
3. I'm back to basic web hosting, and the direct path will bring up each non-httpS page noted above, but regular URL gets 403-forbidden error. So I have to type the /index.php
4. I found out that uloading a script from a tool I wanted to use installed Apache which conflicted my nginx port 80 access. -Uninstalled that, but still having regular URL problems.
5. Error logs shows permissions issue. -So I'm saying this post is solved for now as root-cause being permissions.